# Extracting a file attachment from an email message and saving it to a file?

Tags: email, pdf, base64

I have an email stored in plaintext (yes, headers, messages, attachments, everything in one plaintext file) and I'd like to extract a PDF document from it. I've copied the base64-encoded text, then ran it through `base64 -d` and `cat`ted it to a file. I then tried opening it up, which didn't work, and it doesn't appear like a PDF file.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I'm fairly certain that it is, indeed, encoded in base64 and that it's a PDF file.

Here is the email:

```
---------- MESSAGE FOLLOWS ----------
Date: Tue, 6 Mar 2012 12:24:24 -0800 (PST)
From: "Outer, Inc." <admin@outer.com>
To: Mike Young <inner@outer.org>
Message-ID: <169371530.01331065464959.JavaMail.admin@outer.com>
Subject: Your results are in, Mike!
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_1998493940.1331065464916"
X-Peer: 127.0.0.1

------=_Part_0_1998493940.1331065464916
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_1_1254200493.1331065464936"

------=_Part_1_1254200493.1331065464936
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Great job, Mike on your baby!
------=_Part_1_1254200493.1331065464936
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Great job, Mike on your baby!</h3>
    </body>
</html>
------=_Part_1_1254200493.1331065464936--

------=_Part_0_1998493940.1331065464916
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="Baby Results.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Baby Results.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9iaiA8PC9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvQ29sb3JTcGFjZS9EZXZpY2VH
cmF5L1N1YnR5cGUvSW1hZ2UvQml0c1BlckNvbXBvbmVudCA4L1dpZHRoIDI1My9MZW5ndGggMTYx
...
HR5P9F0eg4+P8tWzo2bPl6eGcNwyLqqW+chQi7Fo/CTWPUI7Kud1ZYgpcnSg7do4SKpTy10jyggP
1dVbvqS63pYxNl1JGGcvD1P+VFdN2b7O3YBqXTuiRteun3nmUdcoObmr5qduv09
```

Comment: Does it look like plain text? What does `file` say about it?

Comment: Updated the question with the email.

Comment: It decodes fine for me. Run `file x.pdf` and see what it says the file is.

Comment: Seems to be a valid PDF file, but I can't seem to view it with anything.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more information. Maybe the PDF file is damaged, maybe it uses some feature that your viewer doesn't support… Try removing the `MESSAGE FOLLOWS` line and importing the file as a mailbox in some mail reader.

Comment: As another workaround, you could also try gmail and/or google docs.

Comment: What does "can't seem to view it with anything" mean? What do you do and what is the result?

Comment: I couldn't open it with a PDF viewer. In the end, I simply mailed the original message to my Gmail account and verified that it was working.

Comment: If i decode the beginning of your base64 encoded attachment, I get: `%PDF-1.4......`, so that looks like a legit PDF file. In the other hand, if I decode the end, I don't see '%%EOF' which would mark the end of a legit PDF file. It seems that your attachment is truncated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

munpack seems like the tool you want.